# I'm making a Animal Crossing clone, but I'm having problems rendering the Player

Tags: c++, sfml

Recently, I decided to make an Animal Crossing clone in
C++ and SFML 2.1. But I'm having some issues. The Player won't show up when commanded to be rendered. The program will compile and run just fine but the player just won't show up.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

RenderWindow window(VideoMode(700, 500), "Animal Crossing: Old oak");

View view(FloatRect(1000, 1000, 300, 200));

class Villager{
public:
int x, y, w, h;
Sprite pl;
string loadDir;

Villager(int x, int y, int w, int h, Color c, string loadDir){
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->w = w;
    this->h = h;

    Image image;
    image.loadFromFile(loadDir);
    image.createMaskFromColor(Color::Magenta);

    Texture tex;
    tex.loadFromImage(image);

    pl.setTexture(tex);
}

}
};

int main(){

Villager villager(1100, 1000, 100, 100, Color::Blue, "player.png");
view.zoom(5);

Image grasstexloader;
grasstexloader.loadFromFile("grass.png");

Texture grasstex;
grasstex.loadFromImage(grasstexloader);

Sprite grass;
grass.setTexture(grasstex);

while(window.isOpen()){
    Event event;

    while(window.pollEvent(event)){

        if(event.type == Event::Closed)
            window.close();

        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Up))
            villager.moveUp();

        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Down))
            villager.moveDown();

        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left))
            villager.moveLeft();

        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right))
            villager.moveRight();

        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
            window.close();
    }

    window.setView(view);

    window.draw(grass);
    window.draw(villager.pl);
    window.display();
    window.clear();
}

}
```

I've been staring at this code for an hour now. But I just can't find an error!

Please help!

Edit: I solved the problem with the sprite not being visible, but the sprite is just white instead of the appropriate colors. It proboably has something to do with how I load the file. Please post any suggestions you have on how to fix this new problem!

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?  I highly recommend using one.

Comment: @AntonAdamson in what a way did your debugger not work?

Comment: I actually got it to work, but it didn't help.

Comment: You should not use (especially SFML object) as global variable.

Comment: Did you ever make a game before? If not, maybe you should start with something simpler? Tetris, for example?

Comment: Yes I have made a lot more games before but I've never encountered this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sprite is rendered white because in your Villager constructor, you're giving a local Texture variable to setTexture, which then gets destructed at the end of the constructor scope.